# C++ - solve a sudoku game

Tags: c++, recursion, sudoku

I'm new to C++ and have to do a home assignment (sudoku). I'm stuck on a problem.

Problem is that to implement a search function which to solve a sudoku.

Instruction:
In order to find a solution recursive search is used as follows. Suppose that there is a
not yet assigned field with digits (d1....dn) (n > 1). Then we first try to
assign the field to d1, perform propagation, and then continue with search
recursively.
What can happen is that propagation results in failure (a field becomes
empty). In that case search fails and needs to try different digits for one of
the fields. As search is recursive, a next digit for the field considered last
is tried. If none of the digits lead to a solution, search fails again. This in
turn will lead to trying a different digit from the previous field, and so on.

Before a digit d is tried by assigning a field to
it, you have to create a new board being a copy of the current board (use
the copy constructor and allocate the board from the heap with new). Only
then perform the assignment on the copy. If the recursive call to search
returns unsuccessfully, a new board can be created for the next digit to be
tried.

I've tried:

```
// Search for a solution, returns NULL if no solution found
Board* Board::search(void) {
    // create a copy of the cur. board
    Board *copyBoard = new Board(*this);
    Board b = *copyBoard;

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){

              //  if the field has not been assigned, assign it with a digit 
            if(!b.fs[i][j].assigned()){
                digit d = 1;

                     // try another digit if failed to assign (1 to 9)
                while (d <=9 && b.assign(i, j, d) == false){
                        d++;


                      // if no digit matches, here is the problem, how to 
                      // get back to the previous field and try another digit?
                      // and return null if there's no pervious field 
                if(d == 10){
                      ...
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return copyBoard;
 }
```

Another problem is where to use the recursive call? Any tips? thx!

Complete instruction can been found here: http://www.kth.se/polopoly_fs/1.136980!/Menu/general/column-content/attachment/2-2.pdf

Code: http://www.kth.se/polopoly_fs/1.136981!/Menu/general/column-content/attachment/2-2.zip

Comment: Do you have any idea what recursion is at this point and how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no recursion in your code. You can't just visit each field once and try to assign a value to it. The problem is that you may be able to assign, say, 5 to field (3,4) and it may only be when you get to field (6,4) that it turns out there can't be a 5 at (3, 4). Eventually you need to back out of recursion until you come back to (3,4) and try another value there.

With recursion you might not use nested for loops to visit fields, but visit the next field with a recursive call. Either you manage to reach the last field, or you try all possibilities and then leave the function to get back to the previous field you visited.

---

Sidenote: definitely don't allocate dynamic memory for this task:

```
//Board *copyBoard = new Board(*this);
Board copyBoard(*this); //if you need a copy in the first place
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you can try is something like this (pseudocode'ish)

```
bool searchSolution(Board board)
{
 Square sq = getEmptySquare(board)
 if(sq == null)
    return true; // no more empty squares means we solved the puzzle

 // otherwise brute force by trying all valid numbers
 foreach (valid nr for sq)
 {
    board.doMove(nr)

    // recurse
    if(searchSolution(board))
        return true

    board.undoMove(nr) // backtrack if no solution found
 }

 // if we reach this point, no valid solution was found and the puzzle is unsolvable
 return false;

}
```

The getEmptySquare(...) function could return a random empty square or the square with the least number of options left. 
Using the latter will make the algorithm converge much faster.